# Testing and Debugging `awesome/rc.lua`

Tags: lua, awesome-wm, interactive-mode

#### How to run lua commands from `awesome/rc.lua` in an interactive iterpreter?

I'm trying to create some functions in `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` for new key bindings. Sometimes I get an error and I want to test these functions by printing the tables and variables in a command line. I downloaded `lua5.2` and I started playing with the interactive interpreter. I wrote a small script that I run at the beginning of the interactive mode.

I'm having a problem when I `require("gears")` and `require("awful")` and pretty much every other library found in `/usr/share/awesome/lib/`. Here are some examples:

1. When attempting to `require("gears")`, I get the error:

   `/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/wallpaper.lua:17: attempt to index global 'screen' (a nil value)`
2. When removing the line with `require("gears")`, the line `require("awful")`, gives me:

   `/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/tag.lua:603: attempt to index field 'client' (a nil value)`

It seems that for every module in the awesome library, There is some component not known for the lua interpreter. **How do I tell the lua interpreter to be aware of these components?**

I'm not very experienced with lua coding. Am I digging in the wrong place? Is there a different and perhaps better way to test functions from `awesome/rc.lua`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Mod4 + x`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html) runs a Lua interpreter.

`rc.lua` and the various Lua lib files are loaded into an environment provided by the host program (written in C). This is why you have access to the provided [API](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/) elements like `screen` and `client`. See the (partially) responsible file [here](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/e723d183e89091772075d96941b2c1905dd8e87c/luaa.c#L660-L682).

If you're just looking to debug some basic Lua functions in the config file, you could consider simply writing to a file or pipe, rather than stdout, and monitoring that instead.

[`Mod4 + Control + r`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html) restarts Awesome, and reloads the config file.

Comment: `$ awesome-client 'n = require("naughty"); n.notify({preset=n.config.presets.normal, title="debug", text="value"})'`

Comment: @loxaxs post an answer, yours is more helpful

Answer (score 3):

The problems you're facing are caused by the fact that you're running your script outside of the environment provided by `awesome`. One thing you can do to overcome this is add [debug statements](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/naughty.html#notify):

```
naughty = require('naughty')  -- if not yet loaded
naughty.notify({text='some message'})
naughty.notify({text=some_string})
naughty.notify({text=tostring(some_number)})
naughty.notify({text=tostring(#some_array)})  -- for array w/o holes
```

and restart `awesome` ([Mod4 + Control + r](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/awesome/awesome.1.en#Window_manager_control)).

Alternatively you can ask `awesome` to [run a script](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/awesome/awesome-client.1.en) you provide:

```
$ awesome-client '
  naughty = require("naughty")
  naughty.notify({
    text="some message"})
'
```

The thing with this method is, as long as you debug your code, it's probably fine. But if you want to figure out what's going on in some library, like [`lain`](https://github.com/lcpz/lain)... `require` doesn't require files twice. If you want to require a file that has changed since the time `awesome` was (re)started, you've got to [`dofile`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-dofile) (with an absolute path and extension, [`package.path`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) is used only by [`require`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require)):

```
bat = dofile "/usr/share/lua/5.3/lain/widget/bat.lua"
bat({})
```

You can also [define some function](https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/6cwevs/the_purpose_of_run_lua_code/dhysrk9/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in `rc.lua`:

```
function f1()
    naughty.notify{text='some text'}
end
```

and then call it via [`Mod4 + x`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/awesome/awesome.1.en#Window_manager_control).

You can check syntax of `rc.lua` by invoking [`awesome -k`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/awesome/awesome.1.en#OPTIONS).

And in some simple cases where you don't need the `awesome` environment, you can just run standalone scripts (`lua5.3 /tmp/a.lua`, or `/tmp/a.lua` if it has the shabang).